# Can I use custom flags to sencha app build?

Tags: extjs, sencha-cmd

Is there a way to pass custom flags like this:

```
sencha app build --foo=bar
```

Then, access that flag via build.xml ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not an expert on extending sencha cmd but I found this on the docs:
https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/7.6.0/guides/cli_reference.html#cli_reference_-_sencha_ant

In the sample code seems like the custom flag `-Dfoo=42` is possible.